# How to find right data structure for a searching application?

Tags: c++, image-processing, data-structures, stl, computer-vision

My question can be asked in two different aspects: one is from data structure perspective, and the other is from image processing perspective. Let's begin with the data structure perspective: suppose now I have a component composed of several small items as the following class shows:

```
class Component
{
public:
  struct Point
  { 
     float x_;
     float y_;
  };
  Point center;
  Point bottom;
  Point top;
}
```

In the above example, the Component class is composed of member variables such as center, bottom and top (small items).

Now I have a stack of components (the number of components is between 1000 and 10000), and each component in the stack has been assigned different values, which means there are no duplicate components in the stack. Then, if one small item in the component, for example, 'center' in the illustrated class is known, we can find the unique component in the stack. After that, we can retrieve other properties in the component. Then my question is, how to build a right container data structure to make the searching easier? Now I am considering to use vector and find algorithm in STL(Pseudocode）:

```
vector<Component> comArray;
comArray.push_back( component1);
.....
comArray.push_back(componentn);
find(comArray.begin(), comArray.end(), center);
```

I was wondering whether there are more efficient containers to solve this problem.

I can also explain my question from image processing perspective. In image processing, connect component analysis is a very important step for object recognition. Now for my application I can obtain all the connect components in the image, and I also find interesting objects should fulfill the following requirement: their connect component centers should be in a specific range. Therefore, given this constraint, I can eliminate many connected components and then work on the candidate ones. The key step in the above procedure is to how to search for candidate connected components if the central coordinate constraint is given. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to be able to search by every field?

Comment: No. In fact each item in the component can be used as the key searching word. In the question, I use 'center' as the searching key word. It is also possible to only use 'bottom' or 'top'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be able to get them rather fast, here's a little strange solution for you.

Note that it is a *bad* solution general-speaking, but it *may* suit you.

You could make an ordinary `vector< component >`. Or that can even be a simple array. Then make three maps:

```
map< Point, Component *>center
map< Point, Component *>bottom
map< Point, Component *>top
```

Fill them with all the available values of `center`, `bottom` and `top` as keys, and provide pointers to the corresponding Components as values (you could also use just indexes in a vector, so it would be `map< Point, int >`).

After that, you just use `center[Key]`, `bottom[Key]` or `top[Key]`, and get either your value (if you store pointers), or the index of your value in the array (if you store indexes).

I wouldn't use such an approach often, but it could work if the values will not change (so you can fill the index maps *once*), and the data amount is rather big (so searching through an unsorted vector is slow), *and* you will need to search often.

Comment: `map` lookup is O(log(n)), not O(1).

Comment: It is a nice solution, and in my situation the values will not change and therefore I can fill the index map once.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [spatial indexing data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index).

Comment: Thanks, and I am not familiar with this subject. After having a quick look at the link you proposed, I was wondering whether there is a  library like STL to use these data structures. Do you have some simple programs to follow? Thanks.

Comment: @feelfree i'm afraid not, but googling stuff like `quadtree` is sure to turn something up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) or a [hash_map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d462wfh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to efficiently lookup your component based on a "center" value.

```
std::map<Component::Point, Component> lookuptable;
lookuptable[component1.center] = component1;

....

auto iterator = lookuptable.find(someCenterValue)
if (iterator != lookuptable.end())
{
    componentN = iterator->second;
}
```

As for finding elements in your set that are within a given coordinated range. There are several ways to do this. One easy way is to just to have two sorted arrays of the component list, one sorted on the X axis and the other on the Y axis. Then to find the matching elements, you just do a binary search on either axis for the one closest to your target.  Then expand scan up and down the array until you go out of range.  You could also look at using a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and find all the nearest neighbors.

Comment: With floats exact search with `unordered_map` might give unexpected results. And with `map` its one dimensional.

Comment: Good point.  He could consider normalizing his floats into an integer representation.  The fact that the map is 1-d is fine for single element lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access them in const time and don't want to modify it. I think std::set is good choice for you code.

```
set<Component> comArray;
comArray.push_back( component1);
.....
comArray.push_back(componentn);
set<Component>::iterator iter = comArray.find(center)
```

of course, you should write operator== for class Component and nesting struct Point.

Comment: This seems very interesting, but are you sure searching in the std::set will cost const time? Sorry I can not find any document about it.

Comment: @feelfree its not. `set` and `map` lookup both have O(log(N)) complexity.